# Simple program that reads and writes to a pipe

Tags: buffer, tcl, pipe

Although I am quite familiar with Tcl this is a beginner question. I would like to read and write from a pipe. I would like a solution in pure Tcl and not use a library like Expect. I copied an example from the tcl wiki but could not get it running.

My code is:

```
cd /tmp
catch {
    console show
    update
}

proc go {} {
    puts "executing go"

    set pipe [open "|cat" RDWR]
    fconfigure $pipe -buffering line -blocking 0
    fileevent $pipe readable [list piperead $pipe]

    if {![eof $pipe]} {
      puts $pipe "hello cat program!"
      flush $pipe
      set got [gets $pipe]
      puts "result: $got"

    }
}

go
```

The output is `executing go\n result:`, however I would expect that reading a value from the pipe would return the line that I have sent to the cat program.

What is my error?

--
EDIT:

I followed potrzebie's answer and got a small example working. That's enough to get me going. A quick workaround to test my setup was the following code (not a real solution but a quick fix for the moment).

```
cd /home/stephan/tmp
catch {
    console show
    update
}

puts "starting pipe"
set pipe [open "|cat" RDWR]
fconfigure $pipe -buffering line -blocking 0
after 10
puts $pipe "hello cat!"
flush $pipe

set got [gets $pipe]
puts "got from pipe: $got"
```

Comment: I mentioned `after` only for demonstration, sorry if that wasn't clear. It's not a good solution because it always waits a fixed amount of time, and you want the script to respond immediately when there's a line to read. If you use `after` anyway (it's easier than setting up a `fileevent` handler), you should do it *repeatedly* until you get a line with `gets`.

Comment: It was clear. I just needed a quick example that works now, I can always improve the code. I tried fileevent too but probably had an error in my code. Also I want the tcl code to call my own program written in a different language. Thanks again for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing to the pipe and flushing won't make the OS multitasking immediately leave your program and switch to the `cat` program. Try putting `after 1000` between the `puts` and the `gets` command, and you'll see that you'll probably get the string back. `cat` has then been given some time slices and has had the chance to read it's input and write it's output.

You can't control *when* `cat` reads your input and writes it back, so you'll have to either use `fileevent` and enter the event loop to wait (or periodically call `update`), or periodically try reading from the stream. Or you can keep it in blocking mode, in which case `gets` will do the waiting for you. It will block until there's a line to read, but meanwhile no *other* events will be responded to. A GUI for example, will stop responding.

The example seem to be for Tk and meant to be run by `wish`, which enters the event loop automatically at the end of the script. Add the `piperead` procedure and either run the script with `wish` or add a `vwait` command to the end of the script and run it with `tclsh`.

PS: For line-buffered I/O to work for a pipe, both programs involved have to use it (or no buffering). Many programs (`grep`, `sed`, etc) use full buffering when they're not connected to a terminal. One way to prevent them to, is with the `unbuffer` program, which is part of Expect (you don't have to write an Expect script, it's a stand-alone program that just happens to be included with the Expect package).

```
set pipe [open "|[list unbuffer grep .]" {RDWR}]
```

Comment: Some versions of `cat` have a `-u` option to disable output buffering. Doesn't help for any other program.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're executing the code from http://wiki.tcl.tk/3846, the page entitled "Pipe vs Expect". You seem to have omitted the definition of the `piperead` proc, indeed, when I copy-and-pasted the code from your question, I got an error `invalid command name "piperead"`. If you copy-and-paste the definition from the wiki, you should find that the code works. It certainly did for me.